# NodeJS Multicontainer Docker on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS application that communicates with mongodb. 
Both services should run on Elastic Beanstalk in a "multicontainer" Docker container. 
It seams that the mongodb service runs through and works but my NodeJS service doesn't start. It produces empty log files and the server is not available.

I am deploying the container via EB CLI. Starting everything locally via `eb local run` works fine but at the live environment the nodeJS part just doesn't start.

This is my Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "node",
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/node"
            }
        }
    ],
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "MONGODB_DATABASE",
                    "value": "chat_service"
                }
            ],
            "image": "mongo",
            "memory": 128,
            "name": "mongo"
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "node",
            "memory": 250,
            "name": "node",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "node",
                    "containerPath": "/usr/src/app",
                    "sourcePath": "",
                    "readOnly": true
                }
            ],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 3000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

I'm very new to Docker, so maybe I forgot something. Neither the CLI nor in the AWS EB Console any errors are visible and the deployment is processed without an error.

Comment: Did you push your image & use it in JSON file?
Rest looks fine to me as if now.

Comment: @vivekyad4v Do I need to push my code as an image to a registry as I deliver my code to elastic beanstalk with the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it. You can push it to ECR & use it in Beanstalk. This `https://github.com/vivekyad4v/aws-elasticbeanstalk-multi-container` might give you a better idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing to `tag` and `push` & `deploy` your image.

1. Tag your local image w.r.t your registry -

   `$ docker tag node-app:latest a.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node-app:latest`
2. Push your image -

   `$ docker push a.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node-app:latest`
3. Update JSON to use tagged image -

   ```
   "essential": true,
   "image": "a.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node-app:latest",
   "memory": 250,
   ```
4. Deploy to Elasticbeanstalk -

   `$ eb deploy $APP_ENV -l ${BUILD_TAG} --timeout 30`

You can find ref. JSON file -

https://github.com/vivekyad4v/aws-elasticbeanstalk-multi-container